# Solving & Understanding $a≡97\pmod7$ When $1\le a\le7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am asked to solve $a≡97\pmod 7$, from what I understand, this is equivalent to saying $7\mid(a-97)$, and I know that $7\mid a, 7\mid 97$, which means that $a=7e, 97=7r$ for integers $e,r$, therefore, $a-97=7(e-r)$. When I solve for $7\mid 97$, I get $97 = 7 \times13+6$, so a quotient of $91$ and remainder $6$. What I do not understand is how to use this to derive $a$ given $a-97=7(e-r)$ which solves for $e$ and $r$.
When $1\le a\le7$

Comment: $7$ does not divide $97$.

Comment: More broadly, what does "solve $a\equiv 97\pmod 7$" mean?  Most people would say that was solved from the start.  Or, since $97\equiv 6\pmod 7$, you could simplify it a bit and point out that it is the same as $a\equiv 6\pmod 7$.  What more do you want?

Comment: The main point to understand is that the solutions are all $a$ that has the same remainder as $97$ when divided by $7$.

Comment: @Milten oh so its to find out the remainder? What was the reason to have $7|(a-97)$?

Comment: $97 = 7r$ for an integer $r$?

Comment: Let me illustrate with other values: In no particular order, we have $a\equiv 6 \pmod 4$, iff $a$ and $6$ has same remainder mod 4, iff $4\mid(a-6)$, iff $a$ has remainder 2 mod 4, iff $a\equiv 2\pmod 4$, iff $a=2+4k$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. I suggest you stare at these statements for a while and try to convince yourself why they all mean the same same thing

Comment: @Milten This puts the answer into better context, many thanks!

Comment: @jjagmath I took some time to understand this, and found the above congruence works when both $a$ and $b = 97$, have the same remainder. So instead, because $7$ is not a perfect divisor of $97$ I instead have $97 = 7p_2+r$, and $a = 7p_1+r$, therefore, $a-97 = 7(p_1-p_2)$ with the remainders cancelled out by the difference. Because I have $97 = a +7p = 7(p_1+p)+r = 7p_2+r$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing is

> The remainder when $97$ is divided by $7$ should be same as the remainder when $a$ is divided by $7$.

We want to solve $a \equiv 97 \pmod 7$. Equivalently, $7 \mid (a - 97)$. As you see, $7 \nmid 97$, so $7$ can not divide $a$ (think why?). So $a$ will be in the form of $7k + q$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0 < q < 7$. Now,

\begin{align*}
  7 \mid (a - 97) & \implies 7 \mid (7k + q -97) \\
                  & \implies 7 \mid (97 -q) \\
                  & \implies q = 6.
\end{align*}
Now, all possible values of $a$ will be
$$a \in \{7k + 6: k \in \mathbb{Z}\}.$$

Comment: Oh sorry, I just made an edit "on autopilot" without asking. Feel free to revert or object!

Comment: This is what I was looking for so thanks!